# n_dead_tup grows despite pretty agressive autovacuum seetings, drops only after index scan

Tags: postgresql

I have a relatively big (~2tb, ~20 billion rows) database with just two tables

```
autovacuum_max_workers = 6
autovacuum_vacuum_threshold = 40000
autovacuum_vacuum_insert_threshold = 100000
autovacuum_analyze_threshold = 40000
autovacuum_vacuum_scale_factor = 0
autovacuum_vacuum_insert_scale_factor = 0
autovacuum_vacuum_cost_delay = 2
autovacuum_vacuum_cost_limit = 3000
maintenance_work_mem = 4GB
```

With the current load autovacuum starts every minute or two (which I thought was good, since more vacuuming = better)

But the porblem is - n_dead_tup steadily increases over time, and vacuum time grows exponentially as well.

Then after about an hour or two, an index scan happens, with a huge spike in IO, and sometimes hangs the system for long enough for the app to crash.

Is there anything I can do to prevent these spikes? May be force index scans more often?

Here's the graph of n_dead_tup steadily growing, despite autovaccums happening.
[image]

And when the index scan finally happens, the spike in IO would be enormous, making the rest of the chart look like a line.

And in the logs, I can see that each autovacuum takes about twice as much time as the previous did. All untill an index scan happens

```
2022-11-12 19:51:05.036 UTC [67209] LOG:  automatic vacuum of table "public.initial_scores": index scans: 0
        system usage: CPU: user: 5.01 s, system: 3.98 s, elapsed: 16.70 s
2022-11-12 19:52:16.269 UTC [67782] LOG:  automatic vacuum of table "public.initial_scores": index scans: 0
        system usage: CPU: user: 6.38 s, system: 6.32 s, elapsed: 27.73 s
2022-11-12 19:55:27.550 UTC [68810] LOG:  automatic vacuum of table "public.initial_scores": index scans: 0
        system usage: CPU: user: 7.22 s, system: 10.33 s, elapsed: 38.50 s
        
and after some time
2022-11-12 21:30:38.277 UTC [96988] LOG:  automatic vacuum of table "public.initial_scores": index scans: 0
        system usage: CPU: user: 29.21 s, system: 66.48 s, elapsed: 261.49 s
2022-11-12 22:05:23.651 UTC [98593] LOG:  automatic vacuum of table "public.initial_scores": index scans: 1
        system usage: CPU: user: 1278.22 s, system: 239.80 s, elapsed: 2062.45 s
```

There are no long-running queries which could prevent vacuum from cleaning properly, and there are no prepared quueries.

Per request adding verbose output of

```
 vacuuming "ryd-db.public.initial_scores"
launched 4 parallel vacuum workers for index vacuuming (planned: 4)
finished vacuuming "ryd-db.public.initial_scores": index scans: 1
pages: 0 removed, 122251463 remain, 13228190 scanned (10.82% of total)
tuples: 275918 removed, 1578025058 remain, 241296 are dead but not yet removable
removable cutoff: 3503893034, which was 1596319 XIDs old when operation ended
index scan needed: 2593283 pages from table (2.12% of total) had 3961159 dead item identifiers removed
index "pk_initial_scores": pages: 7896774 in total, 0 newly deleted, 0 currently deleted, 0 reusable
index "ix_initial_scores_date_created": pages: 18729021 in total, 0 newly deleted, 0 currently deleted, 0 reusable
index "ix_initial_scores_channel_id": pages: 3291717 in total, 12 newly deleted, 13 currently deleted, 10 reusable
index "ix_initial_scores_date_published": pages: 2625645 in total, 0 newly deleted, 0 currently deleted, 0 reusable
index "ix_initial_scores_category": pages: 2164691 in total, 0 newly deleted, 0 currently deleted, 0 reusable
avg read rate: 84.367 MB/s, avg write rate: 15.163 MB/s
buffer usage: 15364625 hits, 21630601 misses, 3887689 dirtied
WAL usage: 9888050 records, 6215601 full page images, 30970053477 bytes
system usage: CPU: user: 636.32 s, system: 120.53 s, elapsed: 2003.03 s
vacuuming "ryd-db.pg_toast.pg_toast_16418"
finished vacuuming "ryd-db.pg_toast.pg_toast_16418": index scans: 1
pages: 0 removed, 17770543 remain, 890550 scanned (5.01% of total)
tuples: 20012 removed, 87435806 remain, 793 are dead but not yet removable
removable cutoff: 3505488713, which was 94878 XIDs old when operation ended
index scan needed: 179949 pages from table (1.01% of total) had 283573 dead item identifiers removed
index "pg_toast_16418_index": pages: 2735506 in total, 0 newly deleted, 0 currently deleted, 0 reusable
avg read rate: 257.567 MB/s, avg write rate: 13.215 MB/s
buffer usage: 945149 hits, 3758561 misses, 192836 dirtied
WAL usage: 413262 records, 98383 full page images, 448496268 bytes
system usage: CPU: user: 10.31 s, system: 9.47 s, elapsed: 114.00 s
analyzing "public.initial_scores"
"initial_scores": scanned 300000 of 122251463 pages, containing 3959953 live rows and 3253 dead rows; 300000 rows in sample, 1613700159 estimated total rows
```

Autovacuum run when index scan is triggered

```
2022-11-14 00:56:44.889 UTC [640096] LOG:  automatic vacuum of table "ryd-db.public.initial_scores": index scans: 1
        pages: 0 removed, 122251463 remain, 14421445 scanned (11.80% of total)
        tuples: 325666 removed, 1577912706 remain, 309680 are dead but not yet removable
        removable cutoff: 3496504042, which was 3600494 XIDs old when operation ended
        index scan needed: 2469439 pages from table (2.02% of total) had 3578028 dead item identifiers removed
        index "pk_initial_scores": pages: 7893180 in total, 0 newly deleted, 0 currently deleted, 0 reusable
        index "ix_initial_scores_date_created": pages: 18721360 in total, 1 newly deleted, 1 currently deleted, 1 reusable
        index "ix_initial_scores_channel_id": pages: 3291207 in total, 6 newly deleted, 7 currently deleted, 6 reusable
        index "ix_initial_scores_date_published": pages: 2625593 in total, 0 newly deleted, 0 currently deleted, 0 reusable
        index "ix_initial_scores_category": pages: 2164594 in total, 0 newly deleted, 0 currently deleted, 0 reusable
        avg read rate: 86.157 MB/s, avg write rate: 11.919 MB/s
        buffer usage: 16609082 hits, 49454603 misses, 6841583 dirtied
        WAL usage: 9554520 records, 5682531 full page images, 28223936896 bytes
        system usage: CPU: user: 1262.91 s, system: 218.72 s, elapsed: 4484.40 s
2022-11-14 00:57:01.086 UTC [640096] LOG:  automatic analyze of table "ryd-db.public.initial_scores"
        avg read rate: 143.711 MB/s, avg write rate: 1.044 MB/s
        buffer usage: 8007 hits, 297889 misses, 2165 dirtied
        system usage: CPU: user: 9.14 s, system: 1.71 s, elapsed: 16.19 s
```

And without index scan

```
2022-11-14 01:09:21.788 UTC [664482] LOG:  automatic vacuum of table "ryd-db.public.initial_scores": index scans: 0
        pages: 0 removed, 122251463 remain, 7751023 scanned (6.34% of total)
        tuples: 1346523 removed, 1596376142 remain, 248208 are dead but not yet removable
        removable cutoff: 3500120771, which was 583770 XIDs old when operation ended
        index scan bypassed: 1420208 pages from table (1.16% of total) have 1892380 dead item identifiers
        avg read rate: 75.417 MB/s, avg write rate: 14.280 MB/s
        buffer usage: 7023840 hits, 7103108 misses, 1344965 dirtied
        WAL usage: 2307792 records, 585139 full page images, 3890305134 bytes
        system usage: CPU: user: 82.42 s, system: 40.27 s, elapsed: 735.81 s
```

Comment: What is DeadTupInitialScores?  And when the chart looks like a flat line, which chart are you talking about?

Comment: @jjanes, DeadTupInitialScores is n_dead_tup from pg_stat_user_tables.
"And when the chart looks like a flat line" - the BlockIO chart - the one based on 
    (SELECT sum(blks_read) as "Read" FROM pg_stat_database),
    (SELECT sum(blks_hit) as "Hits" FROM pg_stat_database)

I mean that the spike is so high - that the "normal" IO looks like a flat line compared to it.

I seem to have somewhat mitigated the problem by increasing autovacuum_vacuum_cost_delay to 25 (so that autovacuum is not as disruptive to other queries).

But I'm still investigating if there's a bigger problem present

Comment: Your manual vacuum certainly seems to have done a lot of IO.  Maybe we need better quantification of what constitutes a spike.  When I have it log autovacuum runs, I get a lot more output than what you showed in your log file excerpt.  If you condensed that output for readability, could you uncondense it?

Comment: @jjanes, yes, I condensed it, focusing on execution times. I've added some raw logs.

Comment: Why is "ix_initial_scores_date_created" so large compared to the other indexes?  The name implies it is a single-column index, why is it so much larger than the other ones? "pk_initial_scores" also seems kind of bloated.  Maybe you could improve things somewhat by re-indexing those (possibly CONCURRENTLY) to shrink them.

Comment: I am baffled why the two vacuums which seemed to do the same amount of work in terms of scanning tables and indexes and removing tuples, had such different number of buffer misses, 21630601 vs 49454603.  I suspect it was probably something to do with the state of the database at the time they were run, rather than one being manual and the other auto, but I don't know.  Maybe you could collect a few more from each method and see if there is a pattern.

Comment: @jjanes "Why is "ix_initial_scores_date_created"" - could it be because it's actually dateCreated OR dateUpdated (i.e. it's changed on every update), and the table is update heavy? And may be at some point I had sub-optimal vacuum settings and it got bloated?

Answer (score 1):

When vacuum does an index cleanup, it needs to read the entire index(es).  This inevitably means a lot of IO if the index doesn't fit in cache.  This is in contrast to the table scan, which only needs to scan the part of the table not already marked all_visible.  Which, depending on usage, could be a small part of the entire table (which I assume is the case here, otherwise every autovacuum would be consuming huge amounts of IO)

You can force the index cleanup to occur on every vacuum, by setting the vacuum_index_cleanup storage parameter for the tables.  But it is hard to see how this would be a good thing, since the clean up is what is causing the problem in the first place.

Throttling the autovacuum so it can run the index cleanup without consuming all your IO capacity is probably the right solution, which it seems you already hit on.  I would have done this by lowering cost_limit rather than by increasing cost_delay because that would be moving the settings more toward their defaults, but it probably doesn't make much of a difference.

Also, if you partitioned the table by date (or something like that) such that most of the activity is concentrated in one or two the partitions at a time, that could improve this situation.  The cleanup scan would only need to be done on the index(es) for the actively changing partitions, greatly decreasing the IO consumption.

There probably isn't much point in vacuuming the table so aggressively only to bail out and not do the index cleanup scan.  So I would also increase autovacuum_vacuum_threshold and/or autovacuum_vacuum_scale_factor.

However, one thing I can't explain here is the pattern in the n_dead_tup graph.  I can readily reproduce the instant spike down at the end of each autovac (whether it did the index-cleanup or not), but I don't understand the instant spike up.  In my hands it just ramps up, then spikes down, over and over.  I am assuming you are using a version after 11, but which version is it?

Comment: "but I don't understand the instant spike up." - yes, that is very concerning. Some issues with analyze? 

"but which version is it?" - recently upgraded 14 -> 15, and the issue existed in both.

Comment: "But it is hard to see how this would be a good thing, since the clean up is what is causing the problem in the first place." - If I do it manually at smaller intervals - the IO spike isn't as big.

Comment: Do you have bulk inserts or deletes going on?  The spike up could coincide with one of those committing.

Comment: When you do it manually, what parameters do you use for the command? If you do it with VERBOSE, what output do you get?  Doing the index-cleanup more often would not decrease the amount of index reading which happens per cleanup, but it could reduce the amount of writing which happens.   Maybe it is only the writing which is the problem for you?

Comment: No bulk operations are performed.

Comment: I added verbose output to the bottom of the page

Comment: @Anarion I can confirm that the spike back up probably is due to ANALYZE running automatically.  autovac lowers n_dead_tup and autoanalyze shoots it right back up again.  That does seem like a rather questionable design of the stats/autovac system, but I doubt it is relevant to the main issue.